# cpp powers of 2 algorothm

Tags: c++, math

so i want this code to be able to count the exact number of powers of 2 but it won't stop until i put odd number in console , any fixes to my code? Thanks a lot in advance
enter code here :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    int counter=0;
    cin >> a;
    while(true){
        cin >> a;
        if(a%2==1)
            break;

            a/=2;
            counter=counter+1;  
    }
    cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make clear about what you want.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.  That should make it clear what the code is doing when you enter various input.

Comment: So let me make it clear . If i put 3 in console then i have to put 3 more numbers for example 4,8 and 100 . And my code has to output the amount of numbers which are power of 2 , in this case 2

Comment: I just want to count how many 2's power are there

Comment: @geeccc Your code doesn't check if the number is a power of 2. Your code checks if the number can be divided by 2. Hence, it would count "6", as a "power of 2".

Comment: so could u write down what i exactly have to write to make my code work as i want ?

Comment: This code if(a%2==1) breaks out of the loop if the remainder after dividing by two is 1.  That sounds like an odd number to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing some things:

- you were not taking inputs as you want.
- your counting procedure was wrong.

**Soln:**

- If a number `n` is a 2's power, then the `and` operation of `n` and
  `n - 1` must be 0. And in all other cases, the result is not `0`. Say,

  ```
  n = 4 (in binary it is 100)
  n - 1 = 3 (in binary it is 11)
  n & (n - 1) = 0

    100 (4)
  & 011 (3)
  -----------
    000 (0)
  ```
- use this technique

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
      int tests, a;
      int counter = 0;
      cin >> tests;
      for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) 
      {
          cin >> a;
          if ((a & (a - 1)) == 0)
              counter = counter + 1;
      }        
      cout << counter;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate all inputs power of two, I would use a double as input in order to get those exponent less than zero (0.5, 0.25, etc.).

With this aim, due to the fact that doubles are expressed in double-precision floating-point format (as defined in IEEE 754-2008 standard), you only should check that the normalized fraction got after descomposing the number with **std::frexp** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) is equal to 0.5:

```
#include <cmath>

bool isPowerOfTwo(double a)
{
    int exp;
    return std::frexp(a, &exp) == 0.5;
}
```

Then the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

bool isPowerOfTwo(double a)
{
    int exp;
    return std::frexp(a, &exp) == 0.5;
}

int main() {
    unsigned counter = 0;

    while (true) {
        double input;
        std::cin >> input;
        if (!isPowerOfTwo(input)) {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of inputs power of 2: " << counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? Rather than just posting the code explain what was wrong with the original code and what you changed to fix it.